# Detect whether an npm package can run on browser, node or both

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, next.js, node-modules

I'm building a NextJs application which uses a set of abstractions to enable code from both react (Component logic etc.) and node (API logic) to utilize same types and classes. The motive here is to make the development process seem seamless across client side and server side.

For example. a call on `User.create` method of the `User` class will behave differently based on the runtime environment (ie. browser or node) - on the browser, it will call an api with a POST request and on server it will persist data to a database.

So far this pattern worked just fine, and I like how it all turned out in terms of the code structure. However, for this to work, I have to import modules responsible for working on the server and browser to a single module (which in this case is the User class) this leads to a critical error when trying to resolve dependencies in each module.

For example I'm using `firebase-admin` in the server to persist data to the Firebase Firestore. But it uses `fs` which cannot be resolved when the same code runs on the browser.

As a work around I set the resolve alias of `firebase-admin` to false inside the webpack configuration (given it runs on browser) see code below.

```
/** next.config.js **/
webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
if (!isServer) {
    // set alias of node specific modules to false
    // eg: service dependencies
    config.resolve.alias = {
        ...config.resolve.alias,
        'firebase-admin': false,
    }
} else {
  // set alias of browser only modules to false.
    config.resolve.alias = {
      ...config.resolve.alias,
    }
}
```

While this does the trick, it won't be much long until the process gets really tedious to include all such dependencies within resolve aliases.

So, my approach to this is to write a script that runs prior to `npm run dev` (or manually) that will read all dependencies in `package.json` and SOMEHOW identify packages that will not run on a specific runtime environment and add them to the webpack config. In order to this, there should be a way to identify this nature of each dependency which I don't think is something that comes right out of the box from npm or the package itself.

Any suggestion on how this can be achieved is really appreciated. Thanks`

Comment: What about ignoring underlying deps  like `config.resolve.fallback.fs = false`? Or split the implementation to different files like  `.server.js` and `.client.js` then load them respectively?

Comment: @Sin Ignoring underlying deps would work, but still  I could not find a proper list of deps that would not resolve properly on the browser. The one list in webpack docs (under resolve fallbacks), does not have some of the deps used by a package I'm trying to avoid on browser. Splitting would've worked,  but the approach I'm using uses factory method which has to import both server and client classes to create the object based on environment.